# How to exceed 255 characters limit of product tag in Shopify?

Tags: tags, shopify

I am looking for a way to exceed the 255 characters limit on product tag in Shopify admin. Please suggest any way of doing so.

Comment: I think 255 chars is an hard limit on Shopify char fields for strings such as a tag. Could you split your long tag names into multiple tags?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Splitting into multiple I think will also not work for me as that too will have more characters. Limit is on characters and not words, that is the problem. What you say?

Comment: Can you give an example for the tag that uses more than 255 characters?

Answer (score 0):

In general this does not sound like a good idea. If you are trying to embed extra information per item you might want to look at putting that in a snippet file and then formatting your tag like `__extra File1` and then a snippet like the following in your product template:

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
  {%if tag contains '__extra' %}
    {% assign snip = tag | remove_first : '__extra ' %}
    {% include snip %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This would allow you to share large chunks of information per product while not blowing up your tags.

If you adopt this approach then you'll also want to go through your theme and make sure you filter out tags beginning with '__'. e.g.

```
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
 {% assign tag_pref = tag | slice:0,2 %}
 {% unless tag_pref ==  '__' %}
  ... do your tag related layout
 {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply bknights. I was thinking for a way to add more than 255 characters tag in admin as that extra tag will be random and not same for each product. What you say?

Comment: If the text is different for every product then I'd use a meta field. A string metafield will hold around 64k characters.